# How to select * from multiple tables in SQL when "self-joining"?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sequel

This query tries to get information about a company and its parent company:

```sql
select c.*, p.*
from companies c, companies p
where c.parent_id = p.id and c.name ilike '%google%'
```

but this seems to return data from the parent company (the one specified latter) only, and is missing the `c.*`.

Perhaps the reason is that because this is a self-join, the second one overrides the first ones?

I'm using this via the Sequal gem.

Comment: are you sure you are looking well your output? what database engine are you using?

Comment: Good catch @JaimeDrq, added some specifics.

Comment: @Austin oh, that's interesting. Even if it's known that we are looking for only one match via the "join"?

Comment: In all likelihood, you need to give the columns different aliases.  I suspect the problem is columns with the same names.

Comment: @Austin: Explicit join syntax is typically easier to read and advisable. But commas in the `FROM` list are not deprecated and just as "standard".  See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167217/3684

Comment: I think your query is not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe is not what Postgres does for this query. It returns all columns of the table `companies` twice, once for each instance, effectively duplicating column names, which can be a problem for some clients that would expect unique column names.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7348f4598212ef69761bc7f94d505fcb)*